# Disabled one cpu on dual cpu board. Cant connect anymore

Tags: stm32, nucleo

so I wanted to disable one of the two cpus I got on my board (H745ZI-Q). I have both a CM4 and CM7 core. When I was playing around I disabled the CM7 boot with cube programmer - user configuration. However after that I could not connect to the board anymore. BOOT0 -> high did not resolve this and neither did the stm32-utility link. None of the tools can get a connecting to the board.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Connect-under-reset** with an ST-link in the [ST Link Utility](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html) and restore the boot configuration bytes.

Comment: st link utility is not able to get a connection with the board. But it seems to be a known issue loocking at this post in st's forum. I'm in contact with a developer now. Thank you for your quick answer https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000CAsx3kSQB/how-do-i-regain-stlink-connectivity-with-nucleoh745ziq-with-bootcm7-0-and-bootcm4-1